# Key unlocks steering lock but won't turn into the ignition section Hyosung Prima Rally (Scooter)

Tags: key, locks, scooter

I have Rally Prima Scooter and just recently I have been unable to turn the key to the ignition section of the lock. I am able to put the key in and turn it one click to unlock the steering lock but it won't turn any more clicks so I am unable to start the scooter.

Things I have tried:

- Turning the key while moving the wheel into different positions
- CRC
- Silicone lubricant
- Taking the front panel off the scooter and slightly tapping the lock barrel and the key while trying to unlock it

Unfortunately I don't have a spare key so I can't try that but the key doesn't look particularly worn down or damaged. Someone did attempt to steal the scooter about two weeks ago so it is possible that they tampered with the lock then (or possibly damaged it when they were trying to push it away?) but I haven't had any issues with the lock until now.

Any other suggestions for things that I should try? Or is my best bet to try and replace the whole lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remembered that I hadn't posted an answer to this and thought I would just in case someone else has a similar situation.

I ended up taking off the ignition cylinder myself (was easier than I thought). Turns out that the ignition cylinder had a a metal rod inside of it that is supposed to turn when you turn the key but it was broken so instead of turning it just jammed.

Bought a new ignition cylinder from a wrecker for $60 NZD and it was good to go.

Comment: NIce, award yourself the answer so it's marked as answered.